# Intel Xeon or AMD Opteron is better for MSSQL 2012?

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, xeon, opteron

Is there any difference in performance, optimisations in MSSQL 2012 on Opteron and Xeon platform ?

*basically we are thinking about 2 x 6 Cores Xeon E5-1660 or  2 x 16 cores Opteron 6380*

Answer (score 1):

Unless you run an OLAP system the CPU is basically useless. Database servers are a LOT more likely to be limited by RAM and the disc subsystem. CPU is not a primary concern until you get REALLY big.

Comment: Hello TomTom. Probably we have reached the issue with the speed. Our store procedures is really big and there is billions of rows of data which is requesting each second to be extracted and processed. Currently under 2 x 4 core Xeon's we are practically holding then the whole time on 100% CPU usage, and we are on the border line and we need to decide about newer hardware. Any help would be gladly welcomed.

Comment: It really depends then. As you go for low end xeons - go with the opterons instead, but use the more expensive ones that can go into a quad processor board. Then you can upgrade another 2 procesors.... SQL Server is one of the areas I think opterons shine - the cores are slower, but there are TONS of them ;)